# Google chrome displays error on AJAX file upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I am trying to upload an image file to the server asynchronously with the help of AJAX. The file successfully uploads through FIREFOX but not through Google Chrome.

It displays the following error message: Uncaught SyntaxError, unexpected end of input

Googling it led me to possibility of missing a bracket or two, but I couldn;t find any such error in my code. Help?

here's the code:

```
<input type="file" name="profile_image" onchange="uploadedImage(this)"/>

function uploadedImage(image)
{
  var file = image.files[0];
  var name = file.name;
  var size = file.size;
  var type = file.type;
  var msg='';
  if(size>500000)
      msg+="File should not be greater than 500kb";
  if(type!="image/jpeg")
      msg+="Only JPEG images are currently supported";
  if(msg!='')
  {
     alert(msg);
     return;
  }   
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('edit_settings'));
$.ajax(
  {
    url: 'upload_demo_image.php',  //Server script to process data
    type: 'POST',
    xhr: function()
    {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        return myXhr;
    },
      // Form data
    data: formData,
    //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(filename)
    {
       var response = jQuery.parseJSON(filename);
       var newImage=response['filename'][0];
       $("#edit_profile_image_container").html("<img id='edit_profile_image' src='"+newImage+"' alt='Profile Image'/>");
        crop();
    }
 }
 );
```

}

Here's the JSON data returned from server:

```
{"filename":["uploadDemo\/8_demo.jpg"]}
```

PHP code:

```
<?php session_start();
require_once 'myfunctions.php';
if(isset($_FILES["profile_image"]["name"]))
{
$query="SELECT * FROM students WHERE email='$_SESSION[user]'";
$result=queryMysql($query);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$_FILES["profile_image"]["name"]=$row['studentid']."_demo.jpg";
$saveto="uploadDemo/$row[studentid]_demo.jpg";
$tempname=$_FILES["profile_image"]["tmp_name"];
$type=$_FILES["profile_image"]["type"];
$image_check=uploadimage($tempname,$saveto,$type,600);
$filename["filename"][]=$saveto;
header('Content-type :text/JSON');
echo json_encode($filename);
}
?>
```

Comment: Where exactly does that error occur? Ctrl+shift+j, click the down arrow next to error, follow the trace on the right till you reach your code or json response.

Comment: Chrome's console says that the error is in "jquery-1.9.1.js:541". On expanding the details, it displays the following:
success   myfunctions.js:348

Comment: That means Chrome doesn't see the json as valid. Most likely, it's right. Take your json and paste it into a json validator.

Comment: I checked my JSON result generated by Firebug on Jsonlint.com. It says that the JSON is valid!

Comment: Perform that same test with the json returned for chrome. also, i'd suggest removing `var response = jQuery.parseJSON(filename);` and setting the `dataType: json`, though you may also want to add an error handler to your ajax.

Comment: removing the parseJSON throws another error in both the browsers.

Comment: removing parseJSON and setting the datatype to json, and changing variable names appropriately should result in no change in firefox, unless the JSON is in fact invalid.

Comment: I defined the dataType:"json", Chrome did not throw an error this time, but neither was it able to upload the image. And this time, Firefox displayed an error saying "JSON.parse: unexpected character".

Comment: I have updated the JSON output above.

Comment: Is there a new line character or space before or after the returned json?

Comment: No, that is all of it. I can update the SERVER Script if required!

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(JSON.parse('{"filename":["uploadDemo\/8_demo.jpg"]}'))` If it works (which it does), then the returned string from your server most likely contains more than just that. That's about as simplified as that can get.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the json string itself, therefore if it's failing, more than just the json string is being returned.

Comment: The Chrome developer console displays an "OBJECT" with some details for above console.log given by you.

Comment: @Sparky - I updated the code with proper indentation. Moreover, I am using NETBEANS IDE for coding, it has self-indentation. I couldn't find any mistakes in it too. Perhaps, you could help me find my mistake!

Comment: @Kevin B - my server script prints only the json encoded string in PHP. Here, I have updated the Server script too.

Comment: Why am i getting downVotes on this question?

Comment: Could be due to not being able to replicate the problem. Given the json response you are getting, the error  you are seeing shouldn't be happening. The only possible cause for that is the json you are giving us isn't all that is being returned.

Comment: Ok, I can provide you the screenshot of Firebug displaying the actual response by the server. Could you please guide me where can I upload the screenshot to share with you?

Comment: Here are the facts though. The browser says the json is not valid. we can argue all day whether or not it is valid, but that isn't going to change how the browser sees it.

Comment: Imgur would be good enough, though i'm not sure how much it's going to help.

Comment: I am not at all claiming it to be correct! I checked the JSON response and found it to be valid. May be it's not the JSON response that is invalid, but the Javascript function is using something not supported by Chrome! And why is Firefox not throwing in any error, if the JSON is invalid at all! Firefox has the script working all fine, without any error!

Comment: I agree, it's very strange. Remove jQuery from the equation by using `JSON.parse` rather than `$.parseJSON()`, though i don't expect the result to be any different.

Comment: No success still. The same error!

Comment: good, this proves that jQuery has no involvement in the outcome. What does `console.log(filename)` give you?

Comment: console.log in Firebug returns the same JSON output which I updated in the Question itself. While for Chrome, it does nothing except displaying the same error message. Here, I have uploaded a screenshot of Firebug displaying the JSON response.. http://www.4shared.com/download/XpIppfyA/xyz.jpg?tsid=20130903-195954-42b18b31

Comment: Add an error handler: `error: function(jqXHR){ console.log(jqXHR.responseText);}` so that you can get the raw response in chrome easily.

Comment: Nothing still. I added the error handler but it still displays nothing but the same error! It doesn't even display a custom message through the error handler!

Comment: Is your code any different from the code in your question?

Comment: Nothing but only the error handler which I added just now. Everything else is the same.

Comment: still no dataType: "json"? if you do have the dataType, try removing it, and ensure that the console.log in the success is before using JSON.parse

Comment: The result is same as before in both conditions : with dataType, or without dataType. And the console.log is set before parsing JSON.

Comment: `header('Content-type :text/JSON');` can you comment out that line? the way your code is currently written, it expects plain text to be returned.

Comment: Done. Still no change!

Comment: Is that the GIVE UP CALL???

Comment: Sorry, no, i'm just stopping back in between working on my own projects. The problem you are describing simply doesnt make sense.... it shouldn't even be calling JSON.parse before the console.log.

Comment: I just removed the success handler from my code, and it removed the error. But Chrome doesn't upload the file still, while it does so via Firefox. So the problem lies either in the server script, or in the way the form data is being sent(something to do with other ajax handlers).

Answer (score 0):

like @Kevin said in comments:
in php file remove line (I don't think so, it's necessary):

```
header('Content-type :text/JSON');
```

and in js file in ajax opsions add:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

and remove this lines:

```
contentType: false,
processData: false,
```

in success function remove line:

```
var response = jQuery.parseJSON(filename);
```

and make a console.log(filename.filename); // first 'filename' is the parametr of success function, second is the cell name from php array $filename["filename"]

Comment: I have already tried all the above with no success. Please read our discussions.

Comment: contentType and processData need to be false in order to upload the image asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

Changes should be made in the formData object as:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("profile_image",filename);
```

Also, the custom xhr function is not necessary.

Above changes make everything work in Chrome.